How to handle winter-summer time change automatically?
I wanted to make the script handle the time change automatically, to avoid editing the code four times a year (in case of focusing on EU and US time change dates). How to do it?

With the following Boolean variables, you can define cases for both Summer/Winter and Standard Time cases.
// European time change: last Sunday in March and last Sunday in October
SummerTimeEU = (month >= 4 and month <= 9) or  // Must be summer time, it's safe
     (month == 3 and dayofmonth >= 25 and dayofweek == 7) or  // After the last Sunday of March
     (month == 3 and dayofmonth >= 25 and dayofmonth - dayofweek >= 25) or  // After the last Sunday of March
     (month == 10 and dayofmonth <= 25 and dayofweek != 7) or  // Before the last Sunday in October
     (month == 10 and dayofmonth <= 25) or  // Before the last Sunday in October
     (month == 10 and dayofmonth - dayofweek < 25)  // Before the last Sunday in October

// American time change: second Sunday in March and first Sunday in November
SummerTimeUSA = (month >= 4 and month <= 10) or  // Must be summer time, it's safe
     (month == 3 and dayofmonth >= 8 and dayofweek == 7) or  // After the second Sunday in March
     (month == 3 and dayofmonth >= 8 and dayofmonth - dayofweek >= 8) or  // After the second Sunday in March
     (month == 11 and dayofmonth <= 7 and dayofweek != 7) or  // Before the first Sunday of November
     (month == 11 and dayofmonth <= 7) or  // Before the first Sunday of November
     (month == 11 and dayofmonth - dayofweek < 7)  // Before the first Sunday of November

TimeZoneEU = SummerTimeEU ? 'GMT+2' : 'GMT+1'
TimeZoneUSA = SummerTimeUSA ? 'GMT-4' : 'GMT-5'
is_LondonOpen = (hour(time, TimeZoneEU) == 8 and minute(time) >= 0)) and (hour(time, TimeZoneEU) < 16 or (hour(time, TimeZoneEU) == 16 and minute(time) < 30))
is_NewYorkOpen = hour(time, TimeZoneUSA) >= 8 and hour(time, TimeZoneUSA) < 17

